# Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. Heroku deployment

Tags: angular, typescript, heroku, build

```
"@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "2.4.9",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.9",
"@angular/core": "2.4.9",
```

this is my first medium sized angular2 project and I'm getting the following error when trying to deploy to Heroku.

`ERROR in /tmp/build_517db5365a6effb7ffc72a360964722f/src/$$_gendir/app/modules/messages/components/list-messages.component.ngfactory.ts (440,79): Supplied parameters do not
 match any signature of call target.`

package.json scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "heroku-prebuild": "npm install -g http-server",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod",
    "start": "http-server dist/",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Note that this error only occurs when trying to deploy to Heroku, when running `ng build --prod` locally, I do not get the same error, the compilation finishes without errors.

I've been looking for any function lacking the expected parameters, but the component is so simple I really don't see it.

Here's my list-messages.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import { MessagesService } from '../services/messages.service'


@Component({
    templateUrl: 'list-messages.component.html',
    providers: [ MessagesService ],
    styleUrls: ['./list-messages.component.css']
})

export class ListMessagesComponent {

    public messages: any
    public search_q: any
    public errors: string
    public success: string
    public page: any
    private total: number
    private limit: any


    constructor(public router: Router, private messageService: MessagesService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.page = 0
        this.limit = 20
        this.messageService.getMessages(this.page, this.limit)
            .subscribe(res => {
                console.log(res)
                if (res.status == 200 && res.data.length > 0) {
                    this.messages = res.data
                    this.total = res.total
                } else {
                    this.errors = res.message || "Unable to complete operation"
                }
            })
    }

    /**
     * On search event
     */

    onSearch(query) {
        this.search_q = query
    }

    deleteMessage(id) {
        if (id) {
            this.messageService.deleteMessage(id)
                .subscribe(res => {
                    if (res.status == 200) {
                        this.messageService.getMessages(this.page, this.limit)
                            .subscribe(res => {
                                if (res.status == 200) {
                                    this.success = "Message deleted"
                                    this.messages = res.data
                                    this.total = res.total
                                } else {
                                    this.success = null
                                    this.errors = res.message || "Unable to get messages"
                                }
                            })
                    }
                })
        } else {
            this.success = null
            this.errors = "Unknown message"
        }
    }


    // -------- PAGINATION ------- //

    /**
     * Loads next page
     * 
     */

    nextPage() {
        this.page += 1
        this.messageService.getMessages(this.page, this.limit)
            .subscribe(res => {
                if (res.status == 200) {
                    this.success = null
                    this.errors = null
                    this.messages = res.data
                    this.total = res.total
                }
            })
    }

    /**
     * Checks if there is a next page
     */

    hasNextPage() {
        return this.page * this.limit < this.total && this.messages.length == this.limit
    }

    /**
     * Loads previous page
     * 
     */

    prevPage() {
        if (this.page > 0) {
            this.page -= 1
            this.messageService.getMessages(this.page, this.limit)
                .subscribe(res => {
                    if (res.status == 200) {
                        this.success = null
                        this.errors = null
                        this.messages = res.data
                        this.total = res.total
                    }
                })
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks if there is a previous page
     * 
     */

    hasPrevPage() {
        return this.page >= 1
    }

}
```

and here's my messages.service.ts (just in case):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment'
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'


@Injectable()
export class MessagesService {

    private baseUrl:string
    private currentUser:any
    private token:string
    private headers:Headers

    constructor(private http: Http){
        this.http = http
        this.baseUrl = environment.api_url
        this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('current-user'))
        this.token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth-token'))
        this.headers = new Headers()
        this.headers.append("Accept", "application/json")
        this.headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json")
        this.headers.append("x-user-id", this.currentUser._id)
        this.headers.append("x-access-token", this.token)
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves all messages
     */

    getMessages(page?:string, limit?:string) {
        let queryParam = new URLSearchParams()
        queryParam.set('page', page) 
        queryParam.set('limit', limit)
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers, search: queryParam })
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/messages', options)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch(this.errorHandler)
    }

    /**
     * Delete a specific message
     * @param id 
     */

    deleteMessage(id) {
        this.headers.delete('x-message-id')
        this.headers.append('x-message-id', id)
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers})
        return this.http.delete(this.baseUrl + '/messages', options)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch(this.errorHandler)

    }

    /**
     * Error handler for all operations
     * @param {Object} error 
     */

    errorHandler(error) {
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error')
    }
}
```

And my list-messages.component.html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div *ngIf="errors" class="error-container col-md-6">
            <div class="card card card-inverse card-danger">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Error
                </div>
                <div class="card-block">
                    <p>{{ errors }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="success" class="error-container col-md-12">
            <div class="card card card-inverse card-primary">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Success
                </div>
                <div class="card-block">
                    <p>{{ success }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card" *ngIf="messages">
            <div class="card-header">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search
            </div>
            <div class="card-block">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="search_q" [(ngModel)]="search_q" (ngModelChange)="onSearch($event)">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card" *ngIf="messages">
            <div class="card-header">
                <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i> All Messages
                <span class="total-count pull-right"> {{ total }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-block">
                <table class="table table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th> ID </th>
                            <th> Email </th>
                            <th> Message </th>
                            <th> Date sent </th>
                            <th> Actions </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let message of messages | messageFilter:search_q">
                            <td>{{ message._id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ message.email }}</td>
                            <td>{{ message.message | truncate :15 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ message.date_sent | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="mailto:{{ message.email }}" class="btn btn-primary">Respond</a>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteMessage(message._id)"> Delete </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="pagination pull-right">
                    <button class="pagination-button" id="prev-page" (click)="prevPage()" [disabled]="!hasPrevPage()">Prev</button>
                    <button class="pagination-button" id="next-page" (click)="nextPage()" [disabled]="!hasNextPage()">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas or suggestions are extremly welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: The error indicates the issue is in `list-messages.component.ngfactory.ts` file line 440. Post the code from there.

Comment: That's a file generated by angular on compilation. I wished I could access that file, it'll make everything a lot easier!.

Answer (score 1):

All your methods which needs parameter should have a type associated with it, for example Your deletemessage parameter id should have a type,

change it as,

```
deleteMessage(id:any) {
}
```

Comment: Just check if you are passing the parameters for those methods inside the template

Comment: I added my template. I really can't see anything missing. I'm exposing the onSearch($event) method and deleteMessage(message._id) method. The rest is just a for loop and a good ol' HTML.